# Why do we KEEP changing our minds?

Tags: expressions, aspect

why do we say someone '**keeps** changing their mind'? when keeping an opinion or decision is not happening.
I know it means to repeatedly change one's mind but why 'keep'?
I've been wondering this for some time and it is beginning to annoy me. Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: To ***keep doing*** something can simply mean to do it repeatedly. So it's perfectly reasonable to say ***He keeps losing his car keys***.

Comment: The verb "keep" has as its core idea persistent behavior or constancy. So, one who "keeps" the Sabbath is one who is  constant in his observance, and one who "keeps complaining" is one whose complaining is not sporadic but unrelenting.  Will the cheese keep on the pantry shelf?

Comment: It doesn't look like this is going to get reopened, Colin. Why not ask again on English.SE rather than this site?  You can ask how *keep* came to be used this way and tag it 'etymology'.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the Longman's definition of "[keep](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/keep_1)":

> 1. to stay in a particular state, condition, or position, or to make someone or something do this
> 2. to continue doing something or to do the same thing many times

As you can see, it means that you "stay in a particular state". When you "keep changing their mind", the person stays in the state of "changing their mind". Similarly, with definition 2, you could say "someone *continues* to change their mind [repeatedly]".

Comment: I don't think sense #1 is relevant; it's for uses like "to keep warm" or "to keep inside". Your last sentence is right on.